# Code runs 30% slower in .Net Core compared to .Net Framework - any way to speed things up?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core-3.1, .net-4.8

### Background

We are currently going though the process of converting our codebase from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net Core 3.1.

Some of the code is very performance-sensitive. One example is some code that applies a Hamming window filter; I was somewhat dismayed to discover that the .Net Core 3.1-compiled code runs around 30% more slowly than the same code compiled for .Net Framework 4.8.

### To reproduce

I created a multitargeted SDK-style project as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkS>net48;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworkS>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The code for this project is as follows (the important code is inside the `for (int iter = ...` loop):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FooBar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
#if NET48
            Console.WriteLine("NET48: Is 64 bits = " + Environment.Is64BitProcess);
#elif NETCOREAPP3_1
            Console.WriteLine("NETCOREAPP3_1: Is 64 bits = " + Environment.Is64BitProcess);
#else
            Invalid build, so refuse to compile.
#endif
            double[] array = new double[100_000_000];
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 100; ++trial)
            {
                sum(array);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Average ms for calls to sum() = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/100);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static double sum(double[] array)
        {
            double s = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            {
                s += array[i];
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

Timing a *release* x86 build for .Net Core 3.1 and .Net Framework 4.8 I get the following results:

**.Net Core 3.1:**

```
NETCOREAPP3_1: Is 64 bits = False
Average ms for calls to sum() = 122
```

**.Net Framework 4.8:**

```
NET48: Is 64 bits = False
Average ms for calls to sum() = 96
```

Thus the .Net Core 3.1 results are around 30% slower than .Net Framework 4.8.

**NOTE:** This only affects the x86 build. For an x64 build, the times are similar between .Net Framework and .Net Core.

I find this most disappointing, particularly since I thought that .Net Core would be likely to have better optimization ...

Can anyone suggest a way to speed up the .Net Core output so that it is in the same ballpark as .Net Framework 4.8?

---

[EDIT] I've updated the code and the .csproj to the latest version I'm using for testing. I added some code to indicate which target and platform is running, just to be certain the right version is being run.

With this edit, I am basically just timing how long it takes to sum all 100,000,000 elements of a large double[] array.

I can reproduce this on both my PCs and my laptop, which are running the latest Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019 installations + latest .Net Core 3.1.

However, given that other people cannot reproduce this, I will take Lex Li's advice and post this on the Microsoft github page.

Comment: With that you can talk to Microsoft guys directly https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate was your benchmarks as you used just raw code and Stopwatch. Can you try to use BenchmarkDotNet to reverify this? It could be just different core speed during two runs or something else. BenchmarkDotNet is a benchmarking library that is designed to eliminate all other factors

Comment: I found .Net Core to be much faster when I ported my graphics code that runs https://pixeldatabase.Net, which is built in Blazor. Like more than twice as fast for large images, so I guess it just depends on the workload.

Comment: I saw that when I reread it. I edited my comment at the same time you were commenting.

Comment: @Lemm I don't think BenchmarkDotNet is necessary for this particular code. I mean, it's 30% different, and it's using multiple trials.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you try running the same test in x64?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've run your code and observe almost the identical results for both target frameworks and debug/release configuration

Comment: @MatthewWatson May be to obvious but is this debug or release build

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü As I said in my post , it's a release build.

Comment: @Blindy Yes, that's interesting - .Net Framework and .Net Core take about the same time for x64

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Are you definitely running an x86 build?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, just double-checked. The difference is pretty small, about 3-5 milliseconds

Comment: No repro, I see .NETCore faster.  A simple explanation is that you have an older processor that has no AVX2 support yet. Do realize what you're chasing.  The inner loop is executed a billion times, tells us that you have a 3.6 GHz processor and are trying to find a difference of **one** cpu instruction.  That's quite hard to do.  The job that the jitter optimizer is critical.  As-is the test is invalid, it can't do that job reliably when you mix the testing code with the real code.

Comment: Fwiw, the most obvious way to make the code fast is to use Math.Abs() to fill window[] so the if-statement is no longer necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant I originally was using that, and changed it to the inline code to see if that made any difference, but it didn't make any significant difference to the ratio between the two builds.

Answer (score 4):

**Cannot reproduce.**

Looks like **.NET Core 3.1** is faster at least for **x86**. I checked it 5 or more times for each build and the Output is nearly the same.

```
.NET Framework 4.8

Is 64 bits = False
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:01.2679838
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:01.1270864
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:01.1163893
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:01.1271687

Is 64 bits = True
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:01.0910610
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.9695353
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.9601170
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.9696420

.NET Core 3.1

Is 64 bits = False
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9852276
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9493986
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9562083
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9467359

Is 64 bits = True
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:01.0199652
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9763987
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9612935
Computed 4199,580000000003 in 00:00:00.9815544
```

---

#### Updated with new sample

```
NET48: Is 64 bits = False
Average ms for calls to sum() = 110

NETCOREAPP3_1: Is 64 bits = False
Average ms for calls to sum() = 110
```

---

#### Hardware

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz

Base speed: 2,40 GHz
Sockets:    1
Cores:  4
Logical processors: 8
Virtualization: Enabled
L1 cache:   256 KB
L2 cache:   1,0 MB
L3 cache:   6,0 MB
```

---

#### Bonus

If the code is so performance-sensitive, maybe SIMD may help.

```csharp
using System.Numerics;
```

```csharp
const int ITERS = 100000;

int vectorSize = Vector<double>.Count;
Console.WriteLine($"Vector size = {vectorSize}");
            
for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
{
    double windowSum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
               
    for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERS; ++iter)
    {
        Vector<double> accVector = Vector<double>.Zero;
        for (int i = 0; i <= window.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
        {
            Vector<double> v = new Vector<double>(window, i);
            accVector += Vector.Abs(v);
        }
        windowSum = Vector.Dot(accVector, Vector<double>.One);
    }
               
    Console.WriteLine($"Computed {windowSum} in {sw.Elapsed}");
}
```

Awesomeness of **.NET Core** is here :)

```
.NET Core 3.1

Is 64 bits = False
Vector size = 4
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.3678926
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.3046166
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.2910941
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.2900221

Is 64 bits = True
Vector size = 4
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.3446433
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.2616570
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.2606452
Computed 4199,58 in 00:00:00.2582038
```

Comment: `Btw, what kind of performance do you expect on a PC that cannot run x64 app?` Who said that the PC cannot run a 64-bit app? Certainly not me...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I mean some client's PC which is running 32 bit OS.

Comment: I guess what I need to find out is why it is OK on some systems but not on others. I've only tried it on two PCs, but I see the difference in speed on both of those.

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you provide some hardware information? I've added my hardware info to the answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Task Manager => Performance => Right click on CPU => Copy

Comment: Sure, one moment. In the meantime, I've just tried it on my laptop (a third test PC for me) and THAT one shows the same times for both!

Comment: PC showing a difference: CPU

 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz

 Base speed: 3.41 GHz
 Sockets: 1
 Cores: 4
 Logical processors: 8
 Virtualisation: Enabled
 L1 cache: 256 KB
 L2 cache: 1.0 MB
 L3 cache: 8.0 MB

 Utilisation 5%
 Speed 1.56 GHz
 Up time 1:18:13:22
 Processes 273
 Threads 3526
 Handles 130907

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm confused then. I've expected some different CPU.

Comment: @MatthewWatson try SIMD in .NET Core. It will make the code faster than the fastest .NET Framework 4.8 :) Give it a try. And it you'll can forget about initial performance issue then.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken - I was testing the 64 bit version on my laptop. When I try the 32-bit version, the difference is still there, so that's 3/3 systems I've tried all show a difference now. As for the SIMD, that could be an option long term, but we have literally half a million lines of code in our codebase, so we'd have to do performance checks to target any fixes!

Comment: @MatthewWatson "long term" for x4 performance boost for all systems while you're looking for something in rare x86 case that makes approximately no sense in general (except if this is some gov/mil software). I suggest not to spend time on that and try SIMD first, at least you can compare x86 vs x64 performance for it right now and see if it inherits the issue or not. You're moving to .NET Core, why not to try its features e.g. in the most performance-sensitive few lines of code?

Comment: That's what I meant: We would have to focus on just the areas where improving performance would be most impactful. This is medical diagnostic software, by the way, so we have to be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I gave it a try, and I included .Net5 as well, and as expected they're pretty much identical in performance.

I would take this as a sign to use more rigorous testing methodologies (Benchmark.NET), because at this point I'm positive you're not running the correct executable, and Benchmark.NET takes care of that for you.

```
C:\Users\_\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Release\net48>ConsoleApp3.exe
Computed 4199.58 in 00:00:01.0134120
Computed 4199.58 in 00:00:01.0136130
Computed 4199.58 in 00:00:01.0163664
Computed 4199.58 in 00:00:01.0161655

C:\Users\_\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Release\net5>ConsoleApp3
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0269673
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0214385
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0295102
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0241006

C:\Users\_\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1>ConsoleApp3
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0234075
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0216327
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0227448
Computed 4199.580000000003 in 00:00:01.0328213
```

Comment: Nah, I'm definitely running the correct executable - it puts the output into different folders, one called release/net48 and the other release/netcoreapp3.1. However, I just rechecked 64 bit versus 32 bit and I am seeing the times being the same for x64. Are your results from x64 or x86?

Comment: 64 bit, it's the only way .Net's GC works at its fullest.

Comment: Well the results are only meaningful for x86, I'm afraid, since that's where the issue appears to be.

Comment: You'll run into a lot of issues in 32-bit land with .Net, it's generally regarded as a non-platform. Many of the major optimizations only get applied in 64-bit, as well as the aforementioned efficient GC model. Feel free to post your issue in the .Net JIT repository, but don't expect miracles if you can't use the 64-bit runtime.

Comment: `You'll run into a lot of issues in 32-bit land with .Net, it's generally regarded as a non-platform.` Definitely going to have to disagree with that!

Comment: You literally just ran into a (possible) regression issue with it, what do you mean you disagree with that?

Comment: @Blindy I also disagree that the preferred target for .NET is `generally regarded as a non-platform`. So would most MVPs and the entire MS compiler and runtime teams. When you select `Any CPU` the preferred target is x86. Never mind that ARM is going to be a *lot* more important going forward

Comment: Actually it's not in more modern runtimes like Net Core 3 and Net 5. "Prefer 32-bit" is disabled by default. And please don't speak for others.

Comment: @Blindy Well, do be aware that for ARM on Windows, *only* 32-bit builds are available.